# subdifferential set of nested nonsmooth function

Tags: derivatives, convex-analysis, subgradient

I am trying to compute the subdifferential set of the convex function
\begin{align}
f_n(x_1,x_2,\ldots, x_n) := \max(x_1+\max(x_2 + \cdots + \max(x_n,0),0),\cdots0).
\end{align}
I'm considering for now the two dimensional case
\begin{align}
f_2(x_1,x_2) := \max(x_1 + \max(x_2,0),0) \overset{(*)}{=} \max\big\{ x_1 + \frac{x_2+|x_2|}{2},0\big\}
\end{align}
where $(*)$ uses the relation $2\max(a,b) = a+b+|a-b|$.
Now for $g(x) = \max(x,0)$, we have
\begin{align}
\partial g(x) =
\begin{cases}
\{1\},&\text{if $x>0$}\\
\mathrm{conv}(\{1\}\cup\{0\}) = [0,1],&\text{if $x=0$}\\
\{0\},&\text{if $x<0$}
\end{cases}.\tag{$**$}
\end{align}

What is $\partial f_2(x_1,x_2)$? What is $\partial f(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$? Does it help to use $(**)$?

---

**EDIT**:

Here's my attempt.

- $x_1=0$, $x_2=0$: $\partial f(x) = \mathrm{conv}\big( \{(1,1)^\top\}, \{(1,0)^\top\}, \{(0,0)^\top\} \big)$
- $x_1=0$, $x_2<0$: $\partial f(x) = \mathrm{conv}\big( \{(1,0)^\top\}, \{(0,0)^\top\} \big)$
- $x_1+x_2=0$ and $x_1<0$: $\partial f(x) = \mathrm{conv}\big( \{(1,1)^\top\}, \{(0,0)^\top\} \big)$
- $x_1+x_2<0$ and $x_1<0$: $\partial f(x) = \{(0,0)^\top\}$
- $x_1>0$ and $x_2=0$: $\partial f(x) = \mathrm{conv}\big( \{(1,1)^\top\}, \{(1,0)^\top\} \big)$
- $x_1>0$ and $x_2<0$: $\partial f(x) = \{(1,0)^\top\}$
- $x_1+x_2>0$ and $x_2>0$: $\partial f(x) = \{(1,1)^\top\}$